# How easily we can create rounded corner crossbrowser DIV using css

Tags: css

please help me how to create rounded corner crossbrowser DIV using css. thanks

Answer (score 1):

CSS 3 already supports rounded corner.
Check out this link: http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no really easy way that is supported on all browsers. Fortunately, as CSS3 becomes more widely accepted, there will be a way that is supported on an increasing number of browsers.

Until then, you can check out http://www.spiffycorners.com/.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
.box_round {
     -moz-border-radius: 12px; /* FF1+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px; /* Saf3-4 */
          border-radius: 12px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome */
}
```

to support ie also you can use [PIE.htc](http://css3pie.com/).

You can find more information and example of rounded corners [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).