# How to create the upper rounded corner of div and bottom is square?

Tags: asp.net, css

Give the css code for rounded corner of div.
i want to create the rounded corner of div but only upper corner.

Comment: Is, it an order for the Users of SO to give a code to u?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How easily we can create rounded corner crossbrowser DIV using css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793573/how-easily-we-can-create-rounded-corner-crossbrowser-div-using-css)

Answer (score 4):

CSS rounded corners are done using the `border-radius` style.

```
border-radius: 5px;
```

If you want to do specific corners, you can split it out into four separate styles (`border-top-left-radius`, etc) or specify four values for the basic `border-radius` style:

```
border-radius: 5px 0 5px 0;
```

`border-radius` is supported by current versions of all browsers, but older versions may need a vendor prefix (eg `-webkit-border-radius` or `-moz-border-radius`), and may also have different syntax for the separate four corner styles.

Older versions of IE (IE8 and lower) do not support it at all, but there is a good hack to make it work for them called [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie.com)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very good site for creating the CSS code for border radii

http://border-radius.com/